# Am I able to escape from the void in Minecraft?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

Can one escape from void when one falls into it already?

I'm basically asking for some kind of command in Minecraft that saves me from dying. This is all in single-player.

Comment: When you say the "void", do you mean falling out of the bottom of the map? Or are you talking about the End? If you mean falling out of the map then a simple teleport command would save you, if you can type it fast enough.

Comment: Yeah @DBS falling out of the map! Also, isn't falling off the map in the End the same thing? Or am I mistakened? Thanks btw.

Comment: @DBS yeah I think I'm able to type fast enough! LOL

Comment: Falling out is the same anywhere, I just wasn't sure if you were talking about the end (As it's a hard to escape place that lots of people get stuck in)

Comment: Since the only way to fall out of the world in the Overworld is using creative mode to break the bedrock, have you tried flying back up?

Comment: Lol I'm going to try to emphasize NOT creative world.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Until you actually die, you should be able to use the [teleport](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Commands#tp) command:

```
/tp PlayerName X Y Z
```

Where `PlayerName` is your name and X, Y and Z are the desired co-ordinates.

If you keep a tp command for a safe location in your clipboard ready to paste into chat, you should be able to survive falling out of the world relatively easily.

Comment: With some usual installation of plugins on most servers, same saving effect will be with usage of /home, /spawn, or any other command :)

Comment: ty @AntoineHejlík

Comment: Don't forget you can enter creative mode if you have cheats enabled - `/gamemode c`

Comment: Also note that if you can't copy and paste that fast you can use nbt edit

Answer (score 0):

If you're in Creative mode, you can just fly. You can actually hover in the void this way. Although you will die (even in Creative!) if you fall too far into the void, the upper portion of the void won't kill you, and that section is deep enough that you should have more than enough time to start flying and escape.